# Can't find '/cloudfoundryapplication' directory

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vcap/app/dist/cloudfoundryapplication'
```

Environment: node12

I could not figure out what is the use for '/cloudfoundryapplication' path.
Is that healthcheck for couldfoundry Apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These requests are generated by Pivotal/VMware's Apps Manager. When a user navigates to an application in Apps Manager, Apps Manager will probe to see if the application supports this particular endpoint. If it does, then it will expose some additional information in it's UI.

In theory, anyone could implement this interface, but I have only heard about this API being implemented in Spring Boot applications with Actuator support enabled. For non-Java & Spring Boot applications you can simply return a 404, which is usually the default behavior.

See this [knowledge base article](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/What-s-the-request-OPTIONS-cloudfoundryapplication-used-for?language=en_US) for reference.